# CEO yawns at presentation

Tags: professionalism, meetings

The ceo got us all pumped up to come up with a strategy for a new product. When my department presented and I started speaking he walked out to get something. Then when my team presented he yawned a couple times. I took it personally not sure if he did it on purpose. Should I be upset? Our team worked hard on that and I found it insulting.

Comment: None of us here can tell you why your CEO yawned. Maybe he was being deliberately rude, maybe he was tired, maybe he saw somebody else yawning and couldn't help himself. We have no way of knowing.

Comment: @JohnKelly, There is no reason to get upset and view the CEO's actions as insults, and to take it personal.  What did the CEO tell your team after the presentation ? Did he approve your team's plan ? The worst thing that can happen is that the CEO cancel your new plan, and in that case, you still can go to work and get the paycheck.

Comment: A CEO's time is very important. Be positive that he came out to hear you and stay for how much of it he did.

Comment: You should be focusing on questions like: will he can the product? Will he push it further? Is he continuing to fund it? Who will he sack? Or will he employ or divert more staff...

Comment: I saw my CEO and COO yawn in quite a few meetings (job interviews, Businessplan reviews, Annual Meeting) in the last year (Japan). You can tell that they found it important to have these meetings. Nothing to take personally.

Comment: I yawn all the time. Yawning can be a sign of lack of sleep, tiredness, boredom or stress/anxiety. Yes, yawning can be a natural response to stress because it stimulates the vagus nerve. I don't think a CEO would do things like that on purpose. Unless you have more proof, I'd say you're just reading too much into it.

Answer (score 9):

**Usually only teenagers yawn on purpose**

It is quite possible that he is bored, but yawning to deliberately demonstrate annoyance is very immature and would be very unusual unless the CEO were otherwise known to be that way.

You are assuming the worst of someone who was probably just bored and/or tired.

Comment: Tired is more likely. For bored, you look at your phone.